# multilevel sub domain no control over root domain's provider

Tags: dns, routing, subdomain, cname

I have a multi tenancy requirement where I need to host couple of apps in my service cloud (AWS + lambda, EC2, S3). I have a couple of UI apps in Angular(hosted in AWS-S3) and an API in Node (AWS lambda/EC2). For the default client that is me, I can create it like 5 multi subdomains and reroute A record and everything, But for other tenants, they are just going to add an A record to one of their subdomains, they might be using CPanel or any regular service or might be hosted in a VPS (Regular domains).

I have a setup like this, where I created multiple subdomains and changed their A records to point respectively

- api.me.com
- app1.me.com
- app2.me.com
- ...etc...

But for a different tenant I have to create a setup

- api.myservice.tenant-domain.com
- app1.myservice.tenant-domain.com
- app2.myservice.tenant-domain.com

How can I reduce the effort and not run into technical challenges of domains and A Records for my tenant whenever a new tenant joins. Please do consider SSL Certificate challenges for subdomains

I can ask my new tenant options

- Option 1: I can ask my tenant to add an A record to myservice.tenant-domain.com and I use base href for all the apps to be under the same sub-domain, (not preferred)
- Option 2: Ask the tenant to create multi level sub domains and respectively put A records to each app
- Option 3: I can use a wild card multi level of a sub domain. What are the challenges here?

Please help me out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of those look good; but there are other methods:

Option 2b: Ask the tenant to create CNAME records instead, pointing indirectly via some subdomain of your choice. Has no effect on certificates but gives you flexibility in still allowing you to change A records on your own if needed.

Option 2c: Ask the tenant to create a DNAME record, which is also an alias like CNAME, but instead of aliasing the name itself, it aliases all sub-domains. (It's kind of like a "wildcard CNAME.")

For example, a "myservice.tenant-domain.com. DNAME tenant3.your-domain.com." would allow you to create app2.tenant3.your-domain.com on your own behalf and that would automatically become accessible as app2.myservice.tenant-domain.com. However, not all DNS servers support adding DNAME records.

Option 4: Ask the tenant to create an NS record and *delegate* the entire sub-zone to your own nameservers. You'll then be in full control of DNS records. (Of course, then it's your responsibility to provide reliable nameservers.)

It's the same kind of delegation as what happens when you buy a domain, but really it can be done at any level, just by creating NS records, which any DNS server can do. However, it's probably the "highest effort" option on *your* side as far as DNS configuration goes.

As for certificates, it only makes a difference for issuance; client browsers don't care how the sub-domains work behind the scenes so long as the certificate matches the URL – it doesn't matter if the domain is a wildcard, an alias, or something else. For issuance with "HTTP challenge" all options work equally well; for "DNS challenge" NS or DNAME might make things easiest.